# get value from data table specific cell and output to textbox

Tags: c#, datatable, datagridview, textbox

trying to get a value from a data table, and output its contents to a textbox. seems im nearly there but for some reason studio doesnt like dt.rows[][];

ive seen multiple examples online in this format, but i get error CS002, cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'DataGridViewRow'.

im trying to locate the current row, and i can figure out the column either by putting an index number or by using the name of the column if that works better.
here is datatable_selectionChanged

```
private void dt_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = dt.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int col = dt.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(row);
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(col);
       
    }
```

here is my mainform_load

```
private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string file = @"C:\Users\User\OneDrive - Motion Controls Robotics, Inc\Desktop\test inventory\TIS.xlsm"; //variable for the Excel File Location
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //container for our excel data
        DataRow row;
            try
            {
                //Create Object for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel that will be use to read excel file

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(file);

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelWorksheet.UsedRange;

            int rowCount = excelRange.Rows.Count; //get row count of excel data
                int colCount = excelRange.Columns.Count;//number of columns to display
                //Get the first Column of excel file which is the Column Name
                for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount;)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
                    }
                    break;
                }

                //Get Row Data of Excel
                int rowCounter; //This variable is used for row index number
                for (int i = 3; i <= rowCount; i++) //Loop for available row of excel data
                {
                    row = dt.NewRow(); //assign new row to DataTable
                    rowCounter = 0;
                    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++) //Loop for available column of excel data
                    {
                    //check if cell is empty
                    if (excelRange.Cells[i, j] != null && excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                        {
                            row[rowCounter] = excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        excelRange.Cells[i, j].value2 = "Empty";    
                            //row[i] = "";
                        }
                        rowCounter++;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(row); //add row to DataTable
                }

            this.dt.DataSource = dt; //assign DataTable as Datasource for DataGridview

                //close and clean excel process
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelRange);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorksheet);
                //quit apps
                excelWorkbook.Close();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook);
                excelApp.Quit();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing a `System.Data.DataTable` which has a collection of `System.Data.DataRow` with a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`. These are entirely different objects. You can get values by index on `DataRow`, but not `DataGridViewRow`.

You will need to provide more information (more code) so that we understand the current scope better.

Comment: ive added my main in the code to the original question.. i am very confused. ive read about what your saying but havent gotten much clarity.

Comment: @Marius can you explain or show example of the difference between the 2? or help out with the code i have provided?